# how to create a list with a defined length and items in python

Tags: python, list

I have a length as 5
and my_name=A

I want to create a list with a length of 5 and the items should contain my_name

My desired output is,

```
length=5
my_name="A"
desired_list=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"]
```

I tried adding like below,

```
desired_list=[]
for i in range(length):
    desired_list.append(my_name+str(i+1))
```

But I want a solution in a single line.

Comment: How did you try and solve this yourself? Did you google search for solutions?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is being asked here. What have you tried so far and what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I tried adding elements through iteration. I am looking for a solution with a single line

Comment: Please update your question with your current solution and the requirement you just commented.

Comment: question ujpdated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use a list comprehension:

```
length = 5
my_name = "A"
desired_list = [my_name+str(i+1) for i in range(length)]
```